How to get Ubuntu 24.04 Noble Numbat .config Kernel Configuration file
I'm looking for the .config Kernel Configuration file used to compile the kernel of my Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat).
As far as I know /boot/config-6.8.045-generic is not what I'm looking for since it can be changed after the compilation. So far I have checked /proc/config.gz but didn't find anything.
I tried the extract-ikconfig script, but it didn't work. I assume the kernel has been compiled with the CONFIG_IKCONFIG=1.
Also sudo modprobe configs didn't work.
I downloaded the source files with git clone https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/noble, but I didn't find it there either. Maybe I looked wrong.
Could you guys please help me out?
With regards

Could be under /usr/src/ ... Try cat /usr/src/*$(uname -r)/.config

/boot/config-6.8.0-48-generic should be identical to /usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-48-generic/.config and should be the kernel configuration that you would use to compile the kernel from the, for example, 6.8.0-48-generic source code. You might need, or want, to make a few changes such as CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="" see this and this


I'm looking for the .config Kernel Configuration file used to compile
the kernel of my 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat).

It should be under /usr/src/ ... See:
/usr/src/linux

    Contains the source code for the Linux kernel.

/usr/src/linux/.config

    The last kernel source configuration. This file is normally created through the 'make config', 'make menuconfig' or 'make xconfig' steps during kernel compilation.

... from Linux Filesystem Hierarchy.
Actual full path name might vary between distributions, but on Ubuntu:
cat /usr/src/*$(uname -r)/.config

... should get you there.
FWIW and IIRC, CONFIG_IKCONFIG is NOT set by default.
